# Installing Windows 11 in empty HDD with ubuntu 20.04 installed in SSD

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd, bios, xps

I am using dell xps 8950 desktop which came with windows 11 home in the hdd. I added another ssd and installed ubuntu 20.04 on that, which required changing the bios to AHCI from Raid On. After installation windows won't boot up.I am looking for a safest way to install fresh win 11 on that hdd without hampering my ubuntu setup.

Comment: Surely you can reinstall Windows with AHCI and it'll work but that's obviously a question for superuser.com, not here where it's off-topic. But you can also install AHCI support in Windows by changing the mode back to RAID - Ubuntu won't boot but you should be able to boot Windows directly - install what's needed (again, off-topic) then change the mode to AHCI and have the dual-boot again.

Comment: However, it should be noted that no OS in 2022 should be installed in a HDD because for many years now any OS is designed to work in a SATA SSD as a minimum. Installing in HDD will result in a painfully slow performance.

Comment: Is Windows shown on your Ubuntu GRUB menu? If not, run `sudo update-grub` in Terminal to add it. Make sure that when installing Ubuntu it is installed in the same BIOS / UEFI mode Windows is installed in, (most likely UEFI mode). If you unplug the Windows disk while installing Ubuntu, you cant mess it up.

Comment: You may need 22.04. My new Dell with Windows 11 and one NVMe drive installed 22.04 without issue, but automatically used the Intel VMD driver which I believe is the same driver as Windows uses. Linux has had a VMD driver for a while, but not sure if Ubuntu did.The only Windows settings I changed was to turn off bitlocker & fast start up.